# No Module named rplot

Tags: python, pandas

I am taking this code from "Modeling Techniques in Predictive Analytics" by Thomas Miller:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from future_builtins import ascii, filter, hex, map, oct, zip
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tools.rplot import RPlot, TrellisGrid, GeomPoint, ScaleRandomColour
```

**And getting the error:**

> No module named rplot

This code worked at one time.  How can I tell if rplot is in pandas or not?  Is that why I am getting this error?  Could it be removed?

Comment: You're probably using a newer pandas version. rplot was removed in newer versions. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#v0-19-0-october-2-2016

Comment: Thank you, sgrg.  I appreciate it.  KM